# tiff viewer wpf application out of memory

Tags: wpf, memory, thumbnails, tiff, out

I'm working on a Tiff Viewer project which deals with big 24bit colored tif files (>70MB).
Here is the code how I load the tif file:

```
TiffBitmapDecoder tbd = new TiffBitmapDecoder(new Uri(_strTiffPath),BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
_frames = tbd.Frames;
```

I use the default cache option to prevent loading the whole file in memory.

My application has a side thumbnails view (vertical StackPanel with Image), and a Page view which views the selected thumbnail.

I load only visible thumbnails by this code:

```
internal static BitmapSource GetThumbAt(int i)
{
    try
    {
        if (i >= _frames.Count)
            return null;

        BitmapFrame bf = _frames[i];
        bf.Freeze();
        return bf;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My problem is when I scroll down the thumbnails view to load the new visible pages, the memory load increases and I run into out of memory !

I tried to unload invisible pages (that were already loaded) but that doesn't help !

```
img.Source = null
```

Thank you helping me to figure this out.

Comment: I found an article [here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/08/tracking_bitmapsource_memory_usage.html) talking about this problem, but I don't know how to adapt it to my own code. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out !
As mentioned in my previous comment, [this article](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/08/tracking_bitmapsource_memory_usage.html) helped me a lot.
I just adapted it to my code and the memory is now unloading correctly.
Here are the modifications I made to my code:

```
internal static BitmapSource GetThumbAt(int i) 
{
    try
    {
        if (i >= _frames.Count)
            return null;

        BitmapFrame bf = _frames[i];
        BitmapSource bs = bf.Clone() as BitmapSource; //make a copy of the original because bf is frozen and can't take any new property
        BitmapUtility.AddMemoryPressure(bs);
        return bs;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```